# DataFrame Pandas - Flatten column of lists to multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here's my problem. I have a dataframe with x columns and y lines. Some columns are actually lists. I want to transform those columns to multiple columns containing single values.

An example speaks by itself :

My dataframe :

```
            ans_length ans_unigram_numbers  ...  levenshtein_dist  que_entropy
0             [19, 14]             [12, 8]  ...              9.00     3.189898
1                 [19]                [12]  ...              4.00     3.189898
2                  [0]                 [0]  ...            170.00     4.299996
3                  [0]                 [0]  ...            170.00     4.303341
4                  [0]                 [0]  ...            170.00     4.304335
5                  [0]                 [0]  ...            170.00     4.311820
28                [56]                [23]  ...             24.00     4.110291
29                 [0]                 [0]  ...             56.00     4.181720
...                ...                 ...  ...               ...          ...
1976              [24]                [11]  ...             24.00     3.084963
1977              [24]                [11]  ...             24.00     3.084963
1992  [31, 24, 32, 28]    [14, 15, 17, 11]  ...             18.75     3.292770
1993  [31, 24, 32, 28]    [14, 15, 17, 11]  ...             18.75     3.292770

[1998 rows x 9 columns]
```

What I expect :

```
    ans_length_0    ans_length_1    ans_length_2    ans_length_3    \
0             19              14            
1             19                
2              0                
3              0                
4              0                
5              0                
28            56                
29             0                
1976          24                
1977          24                
1992          31              24               32             28    
1993          31              24               32             28    

ans_unigram_numbers_0   ans_unigram_numbers_1   ans_unigram_numbers_2   ans_unigram_numbers_3   \
                   12                       8           
                   12               
                   0                
                   0                
                   0                
                   0                
                   23               
                   0                
                   11               
                   11               
                   14                      15                      17                      11   
                   14                      15                      17                      11   

levenshtein_dist    que_entropy
               9       3.189898
               4       3.189898
             170       4.299996
             170       4.303341
             170       4.304335
             170        4.31182
              24       4.110291
              56        4.18172
              24       3.084963
              24       3.084963
            18.75       3.29277
            18.75       3.29277
```

The newly generated columns should take the name of the old one, adding an index at the end of it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you can use:

```
cols = ['ans_length','ans_unigram_numbers']

df1 = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(df[x].values.tolist()).add_prefix(x) for x in cols], axis=1)
df = pd.concat([df1, df.drop(cols, axis=1)], axis=1)
```

Comment: Worked perfectly with an execution time of 2 seconds for 2000 lines :D Short and fast, thanks a lot, I've been working on it for 4 hours now

Answer (score -1):

Based on @jezrael answer, I created a function that do what is asked, from a given dataframe and a given list of columns :

```
def flattencolumns(df1, cols):
    df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(df1[x].values.tolist()).add_prefix(x) for x in cols], axis=1)
    return pd.concat([df, df1.drop(cols, axis=1)], axis=1)
```